# Discrete numerical derivative with respect to dx > 1

Tags: math, opencv, image-processing, numerical-methods

How can I generate a stencil for a d/d(n*x) operator?

I am writing a program that needs to calculate line derivatives in an image. If we want to calculate the simplest derivative approximation with regards to d/dx, we can run the following operation:

```
diff[x] = -1.0 * image[x] + image[x+1]
```

If I want a more precise calculation of the derivative, I can increase the size of the stencil, and possibly recalculate as:

```
diff[x] = -3./2 * image[x] + 2*image[x+1] - 1./2 * image[x+2]
```

I have been using the finite difference method in obtaining these coefficients.

Now suppose I want to take the derivative in regards to d/d(3*x), I could simply stretch the original stencil like this:

```
diff[x] = -1.0 * image[x] + image[x+3]
```

However, here I am not using the information from image[x+1] and image[x+2] and so the derivative approximation can be greatly improved. How can I generate a stencil that WILL use this information and hence be more accurate?

Comment: Why not to use d/d(n*x) = d/d(x) / n?

Comment: Take d/dx (4x^2) and then substitute y=2*x, take d/dy (y^2) and you will have answered your question.

Comment: d/dx (4x^2) = 8*x; d/dy (y^2) = 2*y = 4*x = d/dx (4x^2) / 2

Comment: So, in this case it works.

Comment: Oops, this formula seems to work at first sight.
Anyway, using d/dx is mostly only reliant on 2 or 3 pixels is susceptible to noise, moreover, results differ when rescaling the image. It is not a consistent result.

Comment: If you want the derivative to be resistant to noise, you can preprocess the image by smoothing it. Smoothing and taking derivative can be combined in a single operator. If the image is scaled, its derivative is scaled with the same factor, so I don't see any problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding of your problem, i woiuld propoise to generate a subsampled image at the desired resolution (for example divided by 3) then apply your original derivative computation method. The subsampling procedure should do proper antialisiasing by applying first a low pass filter on your image (for example using a box or Gaussian blur).

Comment: The folks at the math stack exchange couldn't figure it out either, so I've used your method. Instead of downsampling the image though, I am upsampling the kernel, adding zeroes-padding between nonzero filter coefficients. It works pretty well even though it's not an ideal solution.

Comment: In this case, you might also try Fourier's interpretation of derivatives (multiplying the FFT by j*omega).

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions:

- first, in general, use centered computations. The higher order first derivative is thus `0.5*(image[x+1]-image[x-1])`
- second, use the chain formula to derive "with respect to 3x". In its simplest form, formally, `df/dy = df/dx*dx/dy` which means that `dImage/d(3x) = dImage/dx*(1/3)`
  In brief, just divides by 3.